# need some adjusment(help) with mysql table

Tags: mysql, html

I need to create a 24/7 table in mysql, like the rows should be days(mon, tue...sunday) and the columns should be 24 hours(columns) like(1,2,3,...24).

what i did is created individual tables for days like one table for monday, one table for tuesday and so on, and their columns are 1,2,3,...24.

and finally did a UNION ALL to get all the rows together in the way i wanted, but the problem is the row(table) names are not getting displayed, because the union is only combining the columns and not the table names.

i exactly want  7 rows as days and 24 columns as hours, any help on how to do this.

Comment: This is a terrible schema. I'll answer your question, but I doubt it's what you actually need.

Comment: "and the columns should be 24 hours(columns) like(1,2,3,...24)." Bad idea.

Comment: yeah make 365 tables for each day and one DB for year o_O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an extra column to all your `SELECT`s with the name of the day

```
SELECT 'Sunday', `1`, `2`, `3`... FROM `Sunday`
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Monday', `1`, `2`, `3`... FROM `Monday`
UNION ALL
...
```

Comment: its working but when i do UNION ALL ORDER BY sunday, even sunday is getting displayed, is there a way to get rid of the table name sunday in the columns field?

Comment: I don't understand what `ORDER BY sunday` is supposed to do. Do you want the column to have a name? `SELECT 'Sunday' AS dayofweek`.

Comment: i actually added another column at the beginning of the table and set it as a primary key with auto increment, so when i do a UNION ALL, the auto increment value is also getting displayed, i want to get rid of the auto increment value and add a timestamp in its place, is this possible to do?

Comment: Make a different column, put a timestamp in it, and don't select the primary key column...